# What is the difference between Nginx and Apache?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, comet

I don't quite get what is the difference between Nginx and Apache?

I want to use PHP Comet technique for the chat. I do like that:

```
while($modification_date == filemtime($filename)) { 
    sleep(2); 
}

//$filename was updated and we retrieve new messages and give them to the user with JSON help
```

It of course doesn't work in Apache. Will it work in Nginx?

Do not offer me NodeJS and other, please.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you asking what the difference between them is or why your code won't run on Apache? Please can you make your question slightly clearer?

Comment: @Peter Hamilton: I would like to know both actually, because I think it is related.

Answer (score 2):

Main difference between `Apache` and `Nginx` is one is thread driven and another is event driven. But, I think your question is not clear. They have nothing to do with your code snippet. And first explain why It'll not work in `Apache`.

Answer (score 1):

`Nginx` doesn't automagically make that code work. It will suck equally as bad as it did in Apache. The main problem is that PHP isn't threadsafe and each request needs one forked PHP proc to handle the request. This translates into insanely large amounts of needed RAM to scale to anything of decent size. `Nginx` can get around this problem by a different style of programming (comet) and the help of [an extension](http://pushmodule.slact.net/).